# Is there any need of OAuth(2-legged) on HTTPs

Tags: oauth, https, 2-legged

Is there any need of OAuth(2-legged) on HTTPs.
In 3-legged scenario we use oauth for delegation purpose.
but what is the purpose of Oauth(2-legged) over https.

In my scenario I am consumer and also user,so no need of authorization
and I use https,https is not replayable and also secure channel.
what u say should I use ouath

I am not talking about 3-legged or http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to oAuth specification, [section 11.3](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor27),

> While OAuth provides a mechanism for verifying the integrity of
>   requests, it provides no guarantee of request confidentiality. Unless
>   further precautions are taken, eavesdroppers will have full access to
>   request content. Service Providers should carefully consider the kinds
>   of data likely to be sent as part of such requests, and should employ
>   transport-layer security mechanisms to protect sensitive resources.

It is clear that if your request does not have secure data e.g user_id=2&messageId=33, than there is no need for https, but in 2-legged scenerio, where you are passing password while getting access token, you must have to use https at that time.

In both cases, either 2-legged or 3-legged, the rule is, when you are updating/fetching secure data (e.g. Credit Card updation, payments, passwords), you must have to use https.